# Strange bottom margin on collapsed bootstrap navbar I can't get rid off

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I made a bootstrap navbar that is fixed to top on desktop and is static on mobile. I used the following CSS for this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: relative;
    top: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: none;
}
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
}
```

The position: relative element in the code makes the navbar become static but it also results in a tiny bit of margin below the navbar (max 5px) that I do not want. I looked in dev tools already but cannot figure out why this happens. Is it perhaps some standard bootstrap margin that is being applied that I do not know about? Hope somebody can give me a quick fix on this.

Bootply here: http://www.bootply.com/MMOnKyMb6v

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some standard margin from bootstrap but this can be found if you inspect with firebug.
Since bootstrap adds a lot of classes you would have to go through each of the divs wrapping the menu and turn of margin bottom in them if any, to see the result

Comment: And that is what I did but I did not find anything that explains this margin. Also tried adding negative margins but this does not work neither. So I was hoping someone here maybe knows how to solve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please, enter the code here : http://www.bootply.com/new

In this way we can help you better

Comment: Try to add :                                                 .navbar {
  margin-bottom : 0px;
  }

Comment: Is this a comment, or an answer?

Comment: Hmm in bootply it does work but in my own code it does not. Must be something else then.